# java.lang.NullPointerException on selecting action-bar item

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.appContext, "Reselected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

My application closes and throws a `Null Pointer Exception` when i re-select the actionbar again. The error seems to be happening inside the above method.

**LogCat:**

```
> 03-19 20:26:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(2506): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 03-19 20:26:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(2506):
> java.lang.NullPointerException 03-19 20:26:54.075:
> E/AndroidRuntime(2506):   at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:85)
> 03-19 20:26:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(2506):   at
> android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:226) 03-19 20:26:54.075:
> E/AndroidRuntime(2506):   at
> com.example.MyTabsListener.onTabReselected(MainActivity.java:94)
> 03-19 20:26:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(2506):   at
> com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:453)
> 03-19 20:26:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(2506):   at
> com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$TabImpl.select(ActionBarImpl.java:787)
> 03-19 20:26:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(2506):   at
> com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$TabClickListener.onClick(ActionBarView.java:950)
> 03-19 20:26:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(2506):   at
> android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3100) 03-19 20:26:54.075:
> E/AndroidRuntime(2506):   at
> android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11644) 03-19
> 20:26:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(2506):     at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) 03-19
> 20:26:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(2506):     at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 03-19
> 20:26:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(2506):     at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126) 03-19 20:26:54.075:
> E/AndroidRuntime(2506):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997) 03-19
> 20:26:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(2506):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 03-19
> 20:26:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(2506):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491) 03-19 20:26:54.075:
> E/AndroidRuntime(2506):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
> 03-19 20:26:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(2506):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599) 03-19
> 20:26:54.075: E/AndroidRuntime(2506):     at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 03-19 20:31:54.545:
> I/Process(2506): Sending signal. PID: 2506 SIG: 9
```

Comment: The logcat tells you exactly where it's happening.  Please post it (just the relevant part please)

Comment: Don't think so, please post all Exception and snippets of relevant code

Comment: Use like this     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Reselected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: @TGMCians: No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope [I get this error]

Comment: trivially, `MainActivity.appContext` is null. You need to find yourself a proper context.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.appContext, "Reselected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

with

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Reselected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```